# From a dictionary made of multiple lists choose one element from each

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, random

Lets say I have a dictionary of lists like this:

```
lists= {'pet': ["dog", "cat", "parrot"],
        'amount': [1,2,3],
        'food': ["canned", "dry"]}
```

And I want to pick one element from each list, randomly, so the result is like this:

```
{'amount': 2, 'food': 'canned', 'pet': 'cat'}
```

Which would the simplest way to achieve it using Python?

Comment: Use the random module, iterate over the dictionary, and choose a random element from each of it's values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)?

```
from random import choice

{k: choice(v) for k in lists.items()}  # use lists.iteritems() in python 2.x 
# {'pet': 'parrot', 'amount': 3, 'food': 'canned'}
```

---

Or, if you want to update `lists` in-place, use

```
for k, v in lists.items():
    lists[k] = choice(v)

lists
# {'pet': 'parrot', 'amount': 3, 'food': 'canned'}
```

---

Alternatively, if you have a version of python that supports ordered builtin dictionaries (>= cpython3.6, >= python3.7), you can try using `map` as a functional alternative:

```
dict(zip(lists, map(choice, lists.values())))
# {'pet': 'parrot', 'amount': 2, 'food': 'dry'}
```

Personally I like the first two options though.

Comment: ~~for the first example, `{k: choice(v) for k, v in lists.items()}` might be a little cleaner.~~ quick on the edit! nice.

Comment: The first solution is perfect, since I want to be able to generate more than one result, not modify the list.

Comment: @acushner Yes that's fine thank you. I think my previous solution would only be preferable if lists were large and we didn't want to generate an additional view using .items() but this is cleaner, yes.

Comment: how big is the extra view? i always assumed it was just an iterator...

Comment: actually, i'll do some research and see if i find anything interesting.

Comment: @acushner I'm a little rusty on details but these view objects are not iterators, as they don't have a `__next__` descriptor. Try  `next(lists.values())`, it throws `TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not an iterator`. It is a special "view" object implemented in C (assuming cpython).

Comment: thanks! yeah, i tried that first thing and was like "welp, not an iterator"